# DocuSign - Redirect User After Sign - API

Tags: api, docusignapi

I'm using the API to send an envelope and wait for the user to sing the document.

Now what I want is after the sign I want to redirect the user to my app, or at least reach one endpoint of my API.

From what I have understood you have to set the eventNotification when you create the envelope, correct? (/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes)

I'm using this doc as reference:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____39

I try to get an example of how to configure this and send it to the api. But no luck.

Also I know that there is a returnUrl property, but not sure if that apply to this call.

Can any one guide me on how to reach this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/eventNotification), you can configure your Connect listener using envelope API call as well. This is a publish/subscribe architecture, you will be subscribing for the envelope/recipient trigger events, once those events occur DocuSign will publish an XML message to you with some envelope related data.

Branding offers a way to customize the DocuSign experience for both senders and recipients. With the branding controls in DocuSign, as an account administrator you can reinforce your brand presence and reassure signers that documents sent to them through your DocuSign account are coming from your organization. The branding configurations you specify are global and apply to all users on your account and every recipient experience for every envelope sent from your account. Check [Branding Docs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding), [Advanced Branding](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm) to learn to configure branding in your DS Account.

Once Brand is added by an Admin, then you need to open the Template, and select `Advanced Options` section by clicking `Edit` link. On clicking `Edit` link, it will open below popup to configure the Brand in the Branding dropdown.
[image]

Comment: Hi Amit, Ive created the brand, and assign the brand to my template. After that Ive create an envelope and send it to me. But when I finish to sing the document I dont get redirected to the page I configured on the admin site. Just for testing proposes I put https://www.google.com/ on the Signing Completed. And then saved the Brand. Thanks!

Comment: Amit! Sorry Ive got it working never mind thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Event Notifications are for DocuSign Connect configurations - that will allow DocuSign to ping your application when envelope status changes, but won't have any user-facing implications.

If you are using an Embedded Signer/Captive Recipient workflow, you can include a ReturnURL value in your Post Recipient View call. The signer will be directed to that address after the signing session ends. For more information on that, see https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/

If you aren't using Embedded Signers, you will need to set up Account Branding > Destination URLs. More information on that is available here: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm#URLs

Comment: Hi drew, thanks for you answer. There is no way to configure by the api?Is not clear what is the brand for? How I set the brand to a template? Thanks!